# Need to retrieve records from Table3 with relationship Table1--(OneToMany)-->Table2--(OneToOne)-->Table3

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am using django 1.4 and stuck in a situation where i have to retrieve records from database without using **For loop**.

Here is the case :

**Person Model (Table 1)**

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default='')
    degree = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    email = models.EmailField(blank=False, unique=True)
```

**PersonNominationProfile Model  (Table 2)**

```
class PersonNominationProfile(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person', null=False, blank=False,   related_name='nomination_profile')
    person_type = models.ForeignKey('PersonType', default=None, null=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey(SpeakerStatus, related_name='status_nomination_profiles', blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    tier = models.ForeignKey('PersonTier', related_name='tier_nomination_profiles', default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    series = models.ForeignKey(Series, null=False, blank=False)
    year = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

**PersonCertification Model  (Table 3)**

```
class PersonCertification(models.Model):
    nomination_profile = models.OneToOneField('PersonNominationProfile',null=False, blank=False)
    background_check_sent_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False,null=True)
    debarment_check_completed_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False,null=True)
    license_check_completed_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False,null=True)
```

So i am retrieving records from `Person` table and its related data from `PersonNominaionProfile` But unable to get data from `PersonCertification`.

I want to get records from `PersonCertification` without using a for loop.

I tried this

```
all_speakers = Person.objects.filter(nomination_profile__person_type__name='Speaker')\
   .values('id','nomination_profile__series_id', 'nomination_profile__series__name',
           'last_name', 'first_name', 'middle_name', 'degree', 'email'))
```

This gives everything related to `PersonNominationProfile` But how would i get records from `PersonCertification` also.

Please let me know an optimized solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you defined a `OneToOneField` on `PersonCertification`, you should be able to access the reverse relationship via the `personcertification` field on `PersonNominationProfile`. If you use your existing query but add, for example:

```
'nomination_profile__personcertification__background_check_sent_date'
```

to the arguments to `values()`, you should get what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but still having issue regarding duplicate records.I run this for other tables also it gives me data with duplication. `Person.objects.filter(profile__person_type__name='Speaker').values('id','profile__series_id','profile__series__name','last_name','first_name','middle_name','degree','nomination_profile__id','nomination_profile__professionalcontactinformation__method_contact','nomination_profile__personaddress__office_phone','nomination_profile__personsecondarydegree__secondary_degree')`. Any suggestion to this?

Comment: By duplication do you mean multiple rows per `Person`? That is because you are [joining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) to models with `ForeignKeys` (that is, many-to-one) to `Person`. There will be a separate result for each row in the joined table. Note this warning from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#values): "Because `ManyToManyField` attributes and reverse relations can have multiple related rows, including these can have a multiplier effect on the size of your result set... all possible combinations will be returned."

Comment: You are absolutely right and to avoid duplication i tried to place `distinct('profile_id')` at the end but it gives me error that 'DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend'. Is there any alternate option to achieve the same. :)

Comment: That usage only works on PostgreSQL, unfortunately. Even then, you have to use `order_by()` so the database knows which of the matching rows to return. The simplest thing would be to just post-process the results in Python. If you're sure that this has an unacceptable performance penalty in your application, you'll have to figure out how to do that at the database level and use raw SQL. In either case, if you have trouble I would try posting a new question on SO since this is starting to diverge from the original one.